# "too much to finish" and other variants

Tags: sentence-construction

I think these are the exact same meaning ,but I suppose #1 and #2 are common, but #3 is not as common as the other ones are. Is there any reason?

> 1. The other day, I played computer game too much to finish the homework
> 2. The other day, I played computer game so much that I couldn't finish the homework.
> 3. The other day, I played computer game too much that I could finish the homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of all 3 is clear, but they all sound odd. Each would be improved by changing 'game' to 'games'. (or use 'a computer game').

But to sound natural, we would say

> "The other day, I was too busy playing computer games to finish my
>   homework."